# How to read multi directories with Table API in PyFlink?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I want to read multi directories with Table API in PyFlink,

```
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, RuntimeExecutionMode


if __name__ == 'main__':
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH)
    env.set_parallelism(1)

    table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env)
    table_env \
        .get_config() \
        .get_configuration() \
        .set_string("default.parallelism", "1")


    ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE test (
            a INT,
            b STRING
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'filesystem',          
            'path' = '{path}', 
            'format' = 'csv',
            'csv.ignore-first-line' = 'true',
            'csv.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
            'csv.array-element-delimiter' = ';'
        )
    """.format(path='/opt/data/day=2021-11-14,/opt/data/day=2021-11-15,/opt/data/day=2021-11-16')

    table_env.execute_sql(ddl)
```

But failed with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Creating the input splits caused an error: File /opt/data/day=2021-11-14,/opt/data/day=2021-11-15,/opt/data/day=2021-11-16 does not exist or the user running Flink ('root') has insufficient permissions to access it.
```

I'm sure these three directories exists and I have permissions to access it:
/opt/data/day=2021-11-14,
/opt/data/day=2021-11-15,
/opt/data/day=2021-11-16

If not able to read multi directories, I have to create three tables, and union them, which is much more verbose.

Any suggestion is appreciative. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using

```
'path' = '/opt/data'
```

Should be sufficient. The filesystem connector is also able to read the [partition field](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/#partition-files) and perform filtering based on it. For example you can define the table with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
        a INT,
        b STRING,
        day DATE
) PARTITIONED BY (day) WITH (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',          
        'path' = '/opt/data', 
        [...]
)
```

And then the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE day = '2021-11-14'
```

Will read only the file `/opt/data/day=2021-11-14`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works quit well.

Comment: if the PARTITION column is derive from other column, use **DATE_FORMAT** may be help: `day AS DATE_FORMAT('derive_column', 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: one more question, does the above code read the whole path(`'path' = '/opt/data'`), as I noticed that my memory usage is over 80% just to read three days data

Comment: The code above should not read the whole directory. But note that if you use derived columns, there is no optimization that avoid reading all the files.